# Show "NULL" for null values in ASP.NET MVC DisplayFor Html Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

Is there a way to get an `@Html.DisplayFor` value to show "NULL" in the view if the value of the model item is `null`?

Here's an example of an item in my Details view that I'm working on currently. Right now if displays nothing if the value of the Description is `null`.

```
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
</div>
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

yes, I would recommend using the following data annotation with a nullable datetime field in your codefirst model :

```
[Display(Name = "Last connection")]
[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "Never connected")]
public DateTime? last_connection { get; set; }
```

then in your view :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.last_connection)
```

Comment: This should be the actual answer.

Comment: You made my day. But one problem is that the output is in second bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Display a string e.g. "-" in place of null values show via the "DisplayFor" standard helper using a helper extension, i.e. "DisplayForNull"

**1. Create Folder "Helpers" and add a new controller "Helper.cs"**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WIPRO.Helpers
{
    public static class Helpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString DisplayForNull<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {
            var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);

        string valuetodisplay = string.Empty;

        if (metaData.Model != null)
        {
            if (metaData.DisplayFormatString != null)
            {
                valuetodisplay = string.Format(metaData.DisplayFormatString, metaData.Model);

            }
            else
            {
                valuetodisplay = metaData.Model.ToString();

            }

        }
        else
        {
            valuetodisplay = "-";

        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(valuetodisplay);

    }

}
```

**2. In your view**

```
@using WIPRO.Helpers

@Html.DisplayForNull(model => model.CompanyOwnerPersonName)
```

**in place of**

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CompanyOwnerPersonName)
```

Hope it helps ;-)