# How do I display and check a Null value in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an Object, say Employee with the following:

```
 Employee() {
    int id;
    string name;
 }
```

In my view,

I currently do

```
<input type="text" name="employeeName" id="employeeName" readonly="true" value="@Model.Employee.name"/>
```

However, in certain cases the Employee value will be null and this will give me an error, null reference error. Should I do inline checks to return an empty string if it's null or is there a better way?

would the `@HTML.TextboxFor()` method work better in this case?

Comment: Why would you manually create a textbox with `name="employeeName"` which has no relationship to you model and will not be bound on post back (your model does not have a property named `employeeName`)? Use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name, new { readonly = "readonly" })`

Comment: Oh I just made the above up on the fly. But it served as an example.

Comment: You using MVC so make use of its features. Always use strongly typed helpers to bind to your model properties :)

Comment: One additional point:  you can also declaratively say how  to display nulls: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17273132/49251.

Comment: @DWright, `DisplayFormat.NullDisplayText` is only respected by `@Html.DisplayFor()` (not by `TextForFor()` or `EditorFor()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thanks, I hadn't realized that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Html.TextBoxFor` would handle this, yes:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.Employee.Name)
```

This will not cause a null issue.  You can also use your approach with null checks, so your assumption is correct:

```
<input type="text" name="employeeName" id="employeeName" readonly="true" 
  value="@(Model.Employee != null ? Model.Employee.name : "")"/>
```

This is because you are using the objects directly, whereas `TextBoxFor` evaluates the expression tree and handles nulls appropriately.